# What is the meaning of "blunder down"?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

What is the meaning of "blunder down" in the following sentence?

> Sam blundered down the steps.

Does its meaning depend on sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with many words, the meaning depends on context.

The verb *[blunder](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blunder)* means alternatively:

- to move in an awkward way

  > I could hear him blundering around in the darkness.
- to make a (serious) mistake, usually because of not taking care or thinking

  > Police blundered by not releasing more details about the case to focus public interest.

In this case, *blundering down the steps* would have the former meaning, as in

> Sam tripped/staggered/stumbled down the steps.

To take the latter meaning it would be phrased like

> Same blundered *in/by going* down the steps.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation according to [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/blunder) applies definition #1, as a verb:

> blunder, verb
>   1 [intransitive always + adverb/preposition] to move in an unsteady way, as if you cannot see properly
>   blunder about/around:
>
> Someone was blundering about in the kitchen.
>
> blunder into/past/through etc something:
>
> Phil came blundering down the stairs.